# How to check which AWS account and region is an application deployed in

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-regions

We have an organization account (landing zone) with a lot of sub-accounts in it. I have link to an application (Domain name) that is deployed in one of these accounts in one of the regions. How can I figure out which account/region is it deployed it?

I can see the domain in Route 53 service but it does not make it clear where it is mapped to.  I am looking to understand how could I find out where is the EC2 server that the application is running at (FYI: A record for the domain name is pointed to something that looks like d3**********.cloudfront.net

Answer (score 1):

So by looking at the A record in Route53, you will be able to pinpoint the Cloudfront distribution.

Then you can check the [Cloudfront distribution's origin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_Origin.html) which will lead you either to the EC2 address, loadbalancer address or another Route53 A record.

If it is another Route53 A record then it should lead you to either the EC2 or load balancer address. If it leads you to the load balancer you should be able to tell which EC2 by looking at the load balancer's target group.

Comment: Thanks @Victor Wong. I went to the link for Cloudfront distribution's origin and still not sure how do I find it.

Comment: What do you see as the origin?